# Displaying the contents in the <td> vertically

Tags: html, css, json

I am trying to extract the json values and put them into a html table.Although i am successful in inserting the data into the table,i couldnot insert them vertical.Below mentioned screenshot explains the problem.[image]

In the table, the values that are being printed in the row are meant to be displayed vertically.i.e they come under the column name.

Attached is the structure of my JSON file.

```
   {
      "meta":
             {
               "view":
                       {
                       "columns":[
                                    "cachedContents":{
                                                       "name:"name"
                                        }]}}}
```

more details  are available at:

https://data.baltimorecity.gov/api/views/hyq3-8sxr/rows.json

I am trying to print the values that are present in the name column. Below posted is the code.

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript"

 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
 <style>
  #result
  {
   color:red;
  }
 </style>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
     var row = $("<tr/>")
     $("#personDataTable").append(row);
      $.get("https://data.baltimorecity.gov/api/views/hyq3- 
             8sxr/rows.json",function(data)
         {
            $.each(data.meta.view,function(i,obj)
                {
                      if(i=="name")
                         $("#results").append("<p align='center'>"+obj+" 
                         </p>");
                      if(i=="description")
                         $("#results").append("<p align='center'>"+obj+" 
                          </p>");
                      if(i=="columns")
                       var length = data.meta.view.columns.length;
                       for(var ind=0;ind<length;ind++)
                       {
                         if(null!=obj[ind].name)
                         {


                                $("#results").append("<tr>
                             <td>"+"name"+obj[ind].name+"</tr></td>");

                      }

                      if (null!=obj[ind].cachedContents)
                      {

                        $.each(obj[ind].cachedContents,function(j,obj1)
                                      {

                                         if (j=="top")
                                           {
                                             var toplength = obj1.length;
                                             for (k=0;k<toplength;k++)
                                             {
                                                  if(null!=obj1[k].item)
                                                  {


                                 $("#results").append("<li>"+obj1[k].item+"        
                                 </li>");

                         if(obj[ind].name=="name")
                                                       {
                                                          row.append($("<td  
                             align='vertical'>" + obj1[k].item + "</td>"));
                                                          }


                          if(null!=obj1[k].item.human_address)
                                                       {

                         $("#results").append(" 
                          <li>"+obj1[k].item.human_address+"</li>");


                                                       }
                                                  }

                                             }
                                           }
                                     }
                                     );
                                  }

                      }
```

I am trying to print the values that are present in the name column vertically 
Any Suggestions would be highly helpful.

Comment: Would it be possible to share the full JavaScript codes? Because there seems to be a lot of things missing in the codes above.

Comment: can you share a fiddle ?